# mat-select selected option not showing when options are loaded async

Tags: angular, angular-material

The stackblitz below showcases the simplest version of my issue. How do I go about making sure that `selectedFood` is pre-selected when options for the `select` component have been loaded?

```
export class BadgeOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  public selectedFood: Food = { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' };
  private foodSubject: ReplaySubject<Food[]> = new ReplaySubject<Food[]>();
  public foodsObservable: Observable<Food[]> = this.foodSubject.asObservable();

  public ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.foodSubject.next([
        { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
        { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
        { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' },
      ]);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v12-rc-view-engine-rxzqis?file=src/app/badge-overview-example.ts

Comment: In demo its already selected tacos. Then What exactly do you want ?

Comment: Take a look at [compareWith] in [official docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection). Long story short - it's not being shown since those are two different objects.